# A que se debe el siguiente error? AttributeError: choices

Tags: python, api, script, google-colab

Estoy creando un chatbot basico con la api de GPT 3 pero al iniciar la conversacion arroja este error: "AttributeError: choices".
La porcion del codigo que arroja el error es el siguiente:

```
Generar la respuesta de la IA usando GPT-3
   completar = openai.Completion(
   engine="davinci",
   prompt=entrada,
   temperature=0.7,
   max_tokens=1024,
   n=1,
   stop=None,
   frequency_penalty=0,
   presence_penalty=0,
   model=personalidad
    )

   respuesta = completar.choices[0].text.strip()
```

PD: estoy utilizando la api de openai y trabajando con google colab

Utilice el mismo chat gpt para que me ayude con el codigo pero luego de varios intentos no me da la solucion al problema

Comment: Puedes pedir ayuda a chatGPT (https://chat.openai.com/chat).

Comment: Revisa la documentación de la api, pareciera que se está esperando un atributo choices que no estás enviando o estas asumiendo que la respuesta tiene dicho atributo cuando no es así